# Recurrence button greyed out in Outlook 2010

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010

I recently upgraded my Outlook 2007 to 2010 and I've just noticed the Recurrence button is disabled when creating (or editing) an appointment/meeting. But I can still access the recurrence menu via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>. Any ideas on how to enable this button?

[image: Outlook 2010 Toolbar]

Answer (score 0):

I have seen before that you can rename the files `outcmd.dat` & `extend.dat` to `outcmd.dat.old` & `extend.dat.old`.  Make sure outlook is closed first then reopen it. The files should be recreated at program startup. If this doesn't work you can simply rename them back.

Comment: I had tried this before and it didn't work. Actually, I had only found the `extend.dat` (yes, I did I full search on my c: drive).

Comment: odd...both should be there.